# moving a file with spaces in name

Tags: file, unix

I have a file in unix with name as "this is my file.xls"

I want to move it from one folder to other. I wrote the below lines:

```
fileName="this is my file"
myDate=20121125

mv $FIRST_DIR/"${fileName}.xls" $SECOND_DIR/"${fileName}_${myDate}.xls"
```

However, this is not working. I am getting error as "file.xls is not a directory"

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: works for me. What shell are you using?

Comment: @dogbane:  I am using K Shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use escape characters for spaces. So change the variable `fileName` to "this\ is\ my\ file". This ensures that the shell will ignore the spaces and won't consider it as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

In mac, you don't need to use symbol `\`. Simply put the complete filename with space inside double quotes to open.

Like `vim "file to open"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use \ \ to put in white spaces. So

```
mv this\ \is\ \my\ \file this-is-my-file
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

this should work  mv this.is.my.file.xls 
Make sure you put a backlash in front of the dots